# Switch laplacian operator with integration

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I read a formula for laplacian which says:
$$\Delta \int_{B_r(y)}u(x) dx=\int_{B_r(y)}\Delta u(x) dx$$ due to the Laplacian invariance under isometry of Euclidean space.

This doesn't seem trivial to me. Is there any detailed proof or explanation for this formula?

Comment: @Surb according to your formula the formula in the problem is correct too. Simply translate the first integral to become $$\Delta\int_{B_r(0)} u(x+y)dx$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi: indeed, thank you :-)

Comment: @NinadMunshi: Thank you.